# Sitecore Feature ActiveDirectory - adding AD domain to the domainManager doesn't work

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I'm using Habitat Sitecore. It comes with a bunch of foundation and feature projects. One of the feature projects is Sitecore.Feature.ActiveDirectory.
I'm trying to configure domains from patch files. It is outlined by Kam in this [blog](https://kamsar.net/index.php/2016/08/Configuring-domains-from-patch-files/).

In the /App_config/Include/Feature/Feature.ActiveDirectory.config, I added the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <switchingProviders>
      <membership>
        <provider providerName="ad" storeFullNames="false" wildcard="*" domains="ad" />
      </membership>
      <roleManager>
        <provider providerName="ad" storeFullNames="false" wildcard="*" domains="ad" />
      </roleManager>
    </switchingProviders>
    <domainManager>
      <domains>
        <domain id="ad" type="Sitecore.Security.Domains.Domain, Sitecore.Kernel" patch:after="domain[@id='default']">
          <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
          <ensureAnonymousUser>false</ensureAnonymousUser>
          <locallyManaged>false</locallyManaged>
          <isDefault>false</isDefault>
        </domain>
      </domains>
    </domainManager>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

However, I get the following Exception:
A domain specified in the Sitecore.Security.SwitchingRoleProvider provider/domain map could not be found. Domain name: ad
in

```
<add name="switcher" type="Sitecore.Security.SwitchingRoleProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" applicationName="sitecore" mappings="switchingProviders/roleManager" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it work if you add your domain directly to `Domains.config`, located in `App_Config\Security`?

Comment: Yes. but, that's not the ideal solution. Any upgrades to the site would overwrite the  changes.

Comment: Well, sure. But not everything can be patched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domains must be added directly to to `Domains.config`, located in `App_Config\Security`.  It is not able to be patched.  Make it part of your build train.